# How do I include multiple classes in html tag using xml package in python3?

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, elementtree, xml.etree

This is the code snippet attached below. When I check the printed string it shows me `<h1 class= "border_all error_col">` in the output. But in the screenshot attached below, the error_col css class did not apply. I want to know the correct way of applying both css classes to the h1 tag.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
def gen_html_for_mail(error_msgs,total_cases):
    container = ET.Element('div')
    style = ET.Element('style')
    style.text = ".border_all{border: 1px solid black; padding:5px;} .error_col{color:red;}"
    container.append(style)
    h1 = ET.Element('h1', attrib={'class':'border_all error_col'})
    h1.text = "Looks like you failed " +str(len(error_msgs)) + " tests of " + str(total_cases)
    container.append(h1)
    html_str = ET.tostring(container,encoding='unicode',method='html')
    print(html_str)
    return html_str
```

[image: screenshot for the erroneous output]

Comment: There is a syntax error in the definition of `style.text`: "EOL while scanning string literal" (because of the backslash).

Comment: i removed the backslash, yet the problem isnt going

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. The code works for me (text is red).